# What is the difference between SDL_HasEvent() and SDL_GetEventState()?

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I understand that the `SDL_HasEvent(Uint32 type)` check whether type is present in the event queue or not. However, I don't understand what the S`DL_GetEventState(Uint32 type)` does. 
    It is stated in the SDL2.0 wiki that we use `SDL_GetEventState()` to query the current processing state of a specified `SDL_EventType`. I thought these two functions are the same. Could anyone explain to me what the second function does? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SDL_GetEventState is related to the [SDL_EventState](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_EventState) function. The SDL_EventState function allows you to enable and disable events by type. In other words:

SDL_HasEvent tells you whether the event queue contains a certain type of event.
SDL_GetEventState tells you whether the event queue is ignoring a certain type of event.

Answer (score 3):

`SDL_GetEventState` will tell you whether SDL is currently processing or ignoring events of a given type, not whether the queue actually contains those events or not. You can use `SDL_EventState` to turn off entire categories of events.